# brunch config: javascript files exclude *.min.js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, brunch

I understand how brunch handles javascript files, combining them into individual output files:

```
  files:
    javascripts:
      joinTo:
        'javascripts/app.js': /^app/
        'javascripts/vendor.js': /^vendor/
        'test/javascripts/test.js': /^test(\/|\\)(?!vendor)/
        'test/javascripts/test-vendor.js': /^test(\/|\\)(?=vendor)/
```

the 2nd line, for example, takes all the javascript files in the /vendor/ folder and makes the vendor.js

The Regex (/^vendor/) specifies a folder path correct? Any way to have the regex apply to the file names as well? For example if there was a jquery.js and a jquery.min.js, I just want the jquery.js file included. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use functions to test against paths. With them stuff should be simple:

```
joinTo:
  'javascripts/vendor.js': (path) ->
    /^vendor/.test(path) and not /\.min\.js$/.test(path)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can give the paths to be ignored. The regex should match complete path for files, filenames included.

```
paths:
  public: '../deploy'
  ignored: 'vendor/styles/bootstrap'
  test: 'spec'
```

> ignored key: string, regExp, function or array of them. Will check
>   against files that would be ignored by brunch compilator.

But as Amberlamps suggested you can give regex to exclude *.min.js files in the files .

PS:
Never tested it but in the [docs](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/master/docs/config.md) somewhere it is mentioned `/_spec\.\w+$/` matches for user_spec.js.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used brunch before, but if it is using RegExp to find specific paths you can exclude *.min.js files using:

```
/^((?!vendor\/.*\.min\.js).)*$/
```

I used following answer as reference: [Regular expression to match string not containing a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

Comment: Thanks. I think the regex only applies to paths though, not filenames. I may be wrong however....  Likely wrong in fact.. :-)

Comment: Yeah, if it is just applied to paths, this answer is getting you nowhere. Let me know how it worked out.